# Change HTML language from en-US in to en-GB in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This may sound like a simple and trivial question, but I'm using the following tag in a WordPress theme header file:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
```

Which is outputting:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

I wish to change the `lang` attribute to "en-GB" as my blog and the language posts are written in are British English (en-GB) but I can't find where this parameter is set in the WordPress admin settings, and there isn't a value for it in the `wp_options` database table either, which leaves me to believe setting the `lang` value must be some sort of dark art?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the language attribute using:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'en-GB');
```

You can get more information on it at 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language

Comment: **Note to self:** I've noticed that most English sites have this set to `define ('WPLANG', 'en');` — yeah, just `en` and not `en-US` (which is the default).

Answer (score 6):

As for recent version of WordPress 4+ this option

```
define ('WPLANG', 'en-GB');
```

is deprecated, to update the language you need to follow either one of the following methods:

#### Method 1

Inside the **wp-config.php** put the following line:

```
$locale='en_GB';
```

#### Method 2 (recommended)

In database, **XY_options** table to and set an option of ***WPLAN*** to **en_GB** (where XY is the table prefix for your wordpress installation)

exemple queries:

insert

```
INSERT INTO `XY_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES (NULL, 'WPLANG', 'en_GB', 'yes');
```

update

```
UPDATE `XY_options` SET `option_value` = 'en_GB' WHERE `option_name` = 'WPLANG';
```

Comment: Or just visit WP Admin >> Settings >> General and do it via the UI.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Wordpress 5.1.1 , at `wp-config.php`, choose right top line, put

```
$locale='vi_VN';
```

(For example, in case of Vietnamese language)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is with **add_filter**:

```
add_filter( 'language_attributes', 'setLangAttr' );

function setLangAttr() {
    return 'lang="en-GB"';
}
```

Comment: This way worked for me, in 2023 none of the above seem to work anymore

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the discussion here. I had the same need today and found that there is a plugin available for that: [CHL-Change HTML Lang](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/chl-change-html-lang/). The language of the backend/admin interface can be in one language while the posts/articles/portfolios can be set in another language. After activating the plugin hit Settings→General and change the HTML language tag, i.e., en-US, etc.

Comment: …and this is why I hate WordPress development. Need to change a config option? “There’s a plugin for that…”