# forcing cursor be automatically placed at left end of username field in registration form

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hello

in the registration form of my WordPress based website, i need when user clicks on any field (for example username field), the cursor **be automatically placed at left end in that field** & the keyboard be automatically on **ENG-US**.

I need this because some of my users have **right to left language** and perhaps their keyboard is set to right-to-left language when they open registration page & so when they click on any field, the cursor would be placed on the right end in the field (which is undesirable & the user must manually press Ctrl+shift to make cursor be located at the left of the field.)

I want to know whether the above is possible **(forcing cursor to be automatically placed at the left end of the field and language be set to ENG-US)**? I don't know what code should I use and in which file on my WordPress site.

Comment: do you have any code

Comment: Can you post your code please? This makes it easier to help you. You will probably have to use "Locale" to identify whether the user's language is written from left to right or right to left.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-keyboard-caret-position-in-html-textbox)

Comment: no i don't have any code and i asked for the code. thanks Shilly i 'll study that link, but i don't know in which file in my WordPress website i must enter that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dir="rtl" on the input.

```
<input dir="rtl" id="foo"/>
```

or
by css

```
#foo{
  direction: rtl;  /* Right to Left */
}
```

but if you want to do for some countries , you need to check by location with the help of GEO location or google location.

Comment: thanks a lot. above css code made cursor be placed at left end of all fields, but didn't changes they keyboard input language to ENG-US. is that possible as well ?

Comment: share your link

Comment: that's an internal website inside organization. is WordPress based and indeed membership pro plugin provides registration and login forms

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741280/change-html-language-from-en-us-in-to-en-gb-in-wordpress/37571439#37571439

Comment: i tried those workarounds but none of them forced keyboard input language automatically be changed to en-US when we click into input fields of registration form fields.